# How to achieve this effect in Photoshop with two pictures side by side

Tags: adobe-photoshop, sketch-app

[image]

Trying to merge the two pictures (like in the picture), have tryed different brushes, nothimg seem to give anything similar.
What do you use to get this effect?

Thank you

Comment: You might find similar textures by searching for "photoshop abstract grunge brush". Cutting that chunk off the photo would be as simple a using such brush with the eraser tool or with a normal brush tool and a layer mask.

Comment: Hi Mike. Welcome to GDSE.  Perhaps consider that it might not be made using just one brush, but several. Is getting exactly the same result essential?  If so, it might be rather difficult - a trial and error exercise I think.

Comment: @Joonas you are right, found exactly what i needed with a simple brush, thank you "photoshop abstract grunge brush"

Comment: Thank you for explaining how StackExchange works to me @InvariantChange -- all these years and I had no clue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a [watercolour](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-high-res-watercolour-photoshop-brushes-set-2) brush effect using something like a Wacom tablet and pressure sensitive pen.

Nevertheless, still doable to some degree with a mouse and standard Photoshop setup.

Using the Mixer Brush Tool <kbd>B</kbd> on a [Vector Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/photoshop/using/masking-layers-vector-masks.html) and playing around with brush settings, I got this example done in around 30 seconds.

There are plenty of [**free**](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-high-res-watercolour-photoshop-brushes-set-2)  brushes available similar to the effect used in your example, so you should be able to recreate it with no issues at all.

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fill a layer with a solid color.

[image]

Choose `Filter > Render > Fibers` and play with the setting to get a generally dense set of fibers. And then click `Okay`.

[image]

Rotate the fibers 90°. Use the **Magic Wand Tool** with `Contiguous` **unchecked** and click an area or two of the lighter tones and hit delete. This will create gaps in the fibers.

[image]

Add a new layer, fill it with a gradient from the solid color to transparent. And position both layers near where you want the drop off. Add a **layer mask** to the fiber layer and add a black to white gradient on the right side of the fibers to make the right edge softer.

[image]

Add your photo under these two layers.

[image]

Refine as desired.

Comment: Erm... why the down vote?

Comment: I wanna know it too...

Comment: I guess it's because Scott's answer isn't what he was asking? In Mikes example, it's a paint effect brush looking like it's been painted freehand in different directions, possibly made with a pressure sensitive pen. Scott's answer is a horizontal fiber filter.